# CSS style exceptions within a span?

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV with check boxes and labels defined by CSS style when checked:

```
#project input:checked + label {background-color:#787878;color:white;}
```

I want to make two buttons with exceptions to color:white.

Checkbox ID="B" label background-color to turn red and Checkbox ID="C" label background-color to turn blue.  I can't figure it out how to add that specificity.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: (adding HTML code)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="B" value="B" style="display:none;" onclick="document.getElementById('B').style.color = 'red'"><label for="B"> checkbox B </label>
```

This is my failed attempt with a line level change.  I only posted CSS because I thought this could be done in the style.

Comment: can you post your HTML as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the Javascript. Also add `#B, #C { display: none; }` if needed.

```css
#B:checked + label {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
#C:checked + label {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="B" />
<label for="B">test</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="C" />
<label for="C">test</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for `input[id="test"]:checked` this styles inputs with specific id's and checked state.

And you cant style the `background-color` in a checkbox as far as i know.